# Configurationmanager read issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, app-config, configurationmanager

Seems to be lots on this, but just does not seem to work (vs2017 project, C#, project has been upgraded from 2013):

I have both:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
```

At the top of the project, and in the references I have checked under:
project>addreferances>assemblies check both:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration; and
using System.Configuration.install;
```

This code:

```
var alertaddress = Configurationmanager.AppSettings["alertaddress"];
string newmailaddress = alertaddress;
```

And Configurationmanager says does not exist in current context...

All the fixes for this just say add, add ref, and add using so what am I missing?

The app.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
         <add key="alertaddress" value="email@email.com"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Configurationmanager should be ConfigurationManager (case matters).

Comment: damn damn damn that was it

Comment: lol, thank you for the funny reply, you made my day

Answer (score 0):

Configurationmanager should be ConfigurationManager (case matters).